# WiceGrid Calendar assets icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

Time filter icons are not appearing on the production server when the code is deployed. Broken images appear instead, I get

> assets compilation error

.

Comment: It is not about code, dude. It is configuration error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common bug in wice_grid where the icons aren't properly set up for the asset pipeline. Following solves the problem.

In `/initializers/wice_grid_config.rb`, add this line to  `Wice::Defaults::CALENDAR_ICON`

```
# Icon to popup the calendar.
Wice::Defaults::CALENDAR_ICON = "https://raw.github.com/leikind/wice_grid/rails3/vendor/assets/images/icons/grid/calendar_view_month.png"
```